# Marshalling dynamic array to C# delegate (callback)

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I have some native C/C++ code that calls a C# delegate as callback. What's the best practice to pass a dynamic array argument? Actually the C pointer is a data member of a `struct` and I pass the struct to the callback.

Is it OK to do something like this using `IntPtr`?

```
struct Data {
    ... (other data members)
    double* array;
    int size;
};
```

Array is a pointer to an array allocated in my C++ code (just a call to `new` or `malloc`). On the C# side the delegate would expect

```
struct Data {
    ... (other data members)
    IntPtr array;
    int size;
}
```

My concern is... should `IntPtr` be memory allocated using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` or is it also safe if it's memory allocated in my C++ code (`new` or `malloc`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `IntPtr` is correct. The memory is allocated, and deallocate on the unmanaged side. You should therefore do nothing related to allocation and deallocation on the managed side.

Simply read from or write to the array using `Marshal.Copy`. Or if you prefer use an `unsafe` block and interpret the `IntPtr` as a `double*`.